# redirect the user once logged in to the requested page

Tags: jsp, forms-authentication

I have a form realm authentication
with which i am securing a directory "secureUser"

well my question is: - 
How i can redirect the user once logged in to the requested page

the details: -

now i can log on a user using this (login.jsp)

```
    <form action="j_security_check" method="POST" id="login_from">
            <p>
    <input type="text" name="j_username" id="j_username" title="EmailID" />
                        </p>
                        <p>
    <input type="password" name="j_password" id="j_password" title="Password" />
                        </p>
                        <p>
    <input type="submit" name="Submit" id="Login" value="Login" />
                        </p>
            </form>
```

Now a user requests two or more pages in the same session browser (firefox/ie tabs)
"secureUser/one.jsp"
"secureUser/two.jsp"
"secureUser/three.jsp"

Now the user gets a login form page thats login.jsp for all the three requested pages

The user authenticates into the page requested "secureUser/one.jsp"

Now if the user reloads the page "secureUser/two.jsp" or "secureUser/three.jsp"  which is now showing login.jsp
he gets the same login.jsp page

How i can redirect the user after logging in once to the requested page 
such that the page login.jsp  after reloading goes to referred page

I can do this in the login.jsp page

```
        java.security.Principal obj = request.getUserPrincipal();

        if(obj!=null) 
        {
            response.sendRedirect("secureUser/one.jsp");
        }
```

but i cannot get the referred page such as two.jsp or three.jsp

Thanks
Pradyut

Comment: Normally the container managed authentication (the `j_security_check`) already takes care about this. What have you done differently? Are you trying to take over its task programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

you could add a

```
<input type="hidden" name="referrer" value="[[value]]" />
```

to your login form and populate `[[value]]` with the referrer. upon login or when the user is already logged in upon opending the login form, you can redirect your user to that page directly.

you will get the referrer with a call to this function:

```
request.getHeader("referer");
```

Comment: nope... its returning null
as the referer is the server itself.

Comment: the referer normally contains the whole url, not only the server... perhaps a firewall or anything blocking this header? if not, find out the header names with HttpServletRequest.getHeaderNames() and choose the appropriate one

Comment: tried out with
Enumeration enumeration = request.getHeaderNames();
  while (enumeration.hasMoreElements()) {
                    System.out.println("" + request.getHeader(enumeration.nextElement().toString()) );
                }

still could not get the referrer